# race condition in java

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

```
public class LongWrapper {
    private long l;

    public LongWrapper(long l){
        this.l = l;
    }

    public long getL() {
        return l;
    }

    public void setL(long l) {
        this.l = l;
    }

    public void incrementValue(){
        l = l+1;
    }
}
```

Here is my **RaceCondition** Class.

```
public class RaceCondition {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    LongWrapper longWrapper = new LongWrapper(0L);
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                longWrapper.incrementValue();
        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(longWrapper.getL());
    }
}
```

What I am not able to identify is that in this program, why the race condition is not triggering. When this program is run, **output is exactly 2000** each and every time.

But if I change the sequence as shown below, then the race condition is triggering and the output is different as expected.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
t1.start();
t2.start();
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

I am not able to figure out why is this happening?

Comment: You are only incrementing 1000 times, by the time the second `Thread` is done initializing the 1000 increments for the first thread are probably already done. If you initialize both first and then start them directly after each other there is a much higher chance for a race condition to occur.

Comment: The behavior is unpredictable. The same code does and doesn't cause a race condition when I run it repeatedly. Try it a few times.

Comment: I have ran the code on local machine and changed the increment counter from 1000 to 70000 and It is triggering the race condition in both the cases. Please check with changing the value.

Comment: Yeah thankyou @Ben for making this clear.

Comment: This is an example of why testing a program to "prove" that it's free of race conditions is a futile idea. Even if the test passes every time when you run it on your test rig, that doesn't mean that the code will work when it runs on at some customer's site.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, race condition is undetermenistic state. And usually it is hard to reproduce it, especially - in your example, because you use very fast and simple resource for concurrency. And your changes in sequence of threads initialization have no difference from POV of Java language.

So nobody knows why exactly your changes have such effect. It could depend on your OS, hardware, JVM version, compiler version, JVM configuration, compiler's optimizer configuration and even on current processor load.